# datediff of two columns when one column has blank values in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I have two columns with date fields `date1` and `date2`.
In `date2` field i have some blank values but i need to calculate `datediff(day,date1,date2)`.
Both `date1` and `date2` have equal no of entries(including blank values in `date2`field)

my requirement is to calculate `datediff` only for corresponding values in `date1` and `date2` by neglecting blank values in `date2`

Comment: `where date2 is not null`? Maybe you should get a book on sql and read it.

Comment: add an example please.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be when `date2` is `null`?  Do you want to ignore it altogether or return something else?

Comment: blank value is different from NULL. Blank takes character string which is different from NULL.

Comment: @PrasanthG So... you're storing the dates as strings?  You can't have a "blank" `date` or `datetime` datatyped value.  It can only have a value or be `null`.  Still doesn't answer the question of what you want to do with the "blank" ones.

Comment: siyual,   I mean ignore corresponding date1 if date2 is blank and calculate datediff

Comment: database is storing the dates as varchar and i'm casting the dates from varchar to date

Comment: In that case, add the `Where` clause that @Will mentioned.  Unless you're storing dates as strings (which you should *never* do), in which case you'll need to convert that value to a `date` or `datetime` for the `datediff()` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're storing the values as `VARCHAR` (as mentioned in the comments), you can use the following:

```
Select    DateDiff(Day, Convert(DateTime, Date1), Convert(DateTime, Date2))
From      YourTable
Where     Date2 <> ''
And       Date2 Is Not Null
```

You should really be storing any `DATE` or `DATETIME` value as its appropriate datatype to avoid complications, though.

---

To verify that the data is going to convert to a date, in `SQL Server 2012` or later, you can add an additional `Where` clause:

```
Where     Try_Convert(DateTime, Date1) Is Not Null
And       Try_Convert(DateTime, Date2) Is Not Null
```

But for `SQL Server 2008`, you could use `ISDATE()` (but it is notorious for being inaccurate).

```
Where     IsDate(Date1) = 1
And       IsDate(Date2) = 1
```

You might also need to set the `DateFormat` if it is something other than what you're expecting (e.g. `DD/MM/YYYY` vs `MM/DD/YYYY` vs `YYYY-MM-DD`, etc.).

```
Set DateFormat MDY -- Or whatever your date format is in the field.
```

Other than that... just look at your data and see why it's not converting.

Comment: I'm getting the following error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`.

Comment: @PrasanthG This is one of the reasons you shouldn't store dates as strings.  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2008.

Comment: i am using a database in which it stored the date as strings

Comment: @PrasanthG Updated answer - without more information or visibility of the data, this is about the best I can do.